# Managing Azure pipeline from GitHub workflow

Tags: azure, github, pipeline, github-actions

Following some unexplained failures of my build pipeline on GitHub actions on the windows platform I decided to migrate this part only on Azure devops. I have now a GitHub workflow that uses:

```
- uses: azure/pipelines@v1
  with:
    azure-devops-project-url: 'https://dev.azure.com/organization/project-name'
    azure-pipeline-name: 'pipeline-name' # name of the Azure pipeline to be triggered
    azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets.AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}'
```

to run the windows build and tests.

I am now struggling a bit to retrieve and upload my artifact back in GitHub so that it can be deployed on PyPI together with the Linux & Mac artifacts.

My points are:

- The above tasks seems to return as soon as it is launched - which makes sense since you don't want to consume GitHub resources while your pipeline is sunning on Azure. Then how to be notified when it is finished ?
- How to actually retrieve the artifact? On my side I used the snippet below ...

```
  - name: 'Download artifacts from Azure devops build pipeline'
    uses: manishsat/ado-download-artifact@v3
    with:
      buildDefinitionId: 'latest'
      pattoken: ${{ secrets.AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}
      artifactName: 'wh_windows'
      orgName: 'guillaumealleon'
      projectId: 'scikit-decide'
```

but that does not work. First `latest` does not seem a valid argument - I tried with a valid integer  but now face this error

[image: TypeError]

This also resonates with my point 1 - at the time this second task is executed, I am not sure my artifact exists.

Any idea how to move forward?

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of `ado-download-artifact` action in the following link, you should use `projectId` instead of `projectname`, you may have a try:

https://github.com/manishsat/ado-download-artifact/blob/master/action.yml

```
inputs:
  buildDefinitionId:
    description: 'Build Definition Id for which the artifact is going to be downloaded'
  pattoken:
    description: 'PAT token to access build and build artifacts'
  artifactName: 
    description: 'Name of the artifact'
  orgName:
    description: 'Azure DevOps organization name'
  projectId:
    description: 'Azure DevOps projectId for which the build and artifacts belongs to'
```